# BIRT parameters indented

Tags: parameters, indentation, birt

I've been working on a BIRT report and now two of the four parameters are strangely indented when viewed from our Tomcat server. The parameters align normally within the BIRT viewer. 
I've searched all over for some setting that could undo this, with no luck. Just wondering if anyone has run into this before and if you have any suggestions on how to make them line up again! 
Other info: 
- it happens in all browsers. 
- the two non-indented parameters are linked in a "cascading parameter group" (the recent changes) so this is an important clue.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean data or parameters? Can you include an image?

Comment: @JamesJenkins - I wasn't allowed to in my post since I am new to the site. Here is a [link](http://i.imgur.com/cEuwJAd.png)

Comment: I added your image to the question. I have not seen this behavior before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much digging, I found the offending code in:
\webcontent\birt\pages\parameter\ParameterGroupFragment.jsp
At least in our implementation, the parameter group is rendered in it's own table, so it doesn't align with ungrouped parameters. I removed the extra table tags and it all displays properly.